# Not able to compare time properly in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, time

Here is a query that i am using to compare time in codeigniter

```
$present_time = date("h:i a");
$this->db->where('status!=', 'closed ');
$this->db->where('one_hour_break!=', ' ');
$this->db->where("(one_hour_break ='$present_time' or one_hour_break < '$present_time')");
$query = $this->db->get('student');
$final_time = $query->result();

if($final_time)
    {
        echo "true";
    }
else
    {
        echo "false";
    }
```

It is comparing the time properly if it is between 1 and 12 however it is not comparing  time properly between the given time is between 12pm to 1pm and 12am to 1pm

> e.g :
>
> So if  present time: 12:30 pm and one_hour_break: 1:30 pm, then one hour break should be greater than present time, and the result should say false, however it is saying true. Same goes with the time between 12pm to 1pm

Can anyone please tell how to manage this issue

Comment: Maybe you can use "H" instead? So it's 24 hour clock?

Comment: @Andreas there also i am getting issue b/w 24 and 1

Comment: You need to time convert in timestamp and after then you can compare time.

Comment: Try to use time formate in 24hrs

Comment: Do you have the dates in the database? If you add the date you get a "fixed time" not "floating" as you have now. If you don't have the date maybe you can "fake" it?

Comment: @Mandip I think you need the date to make a timestamp. At least a correct timestamp

Comment: @Andreas How can i use date to do so

Comment: "Date format only"? What does that mean? There are a few ways to fix this, the best way is to go back and store the times in the database with "Y-m-d H:i" or something like it. That way you can get a fixed timestamp of when, and not only time of day which is useless most of the times when you develop.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php strtotime converts a date in string format to a numeric value. This value can easily be compared.

Comment: @Andreas Oh i see your point, seems to be working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to fix this, the best way is to go back and store the times in the database with "Y-m-d H:i" or something like it.
That way you can get a fixed timestamp of when, and not only time of day which is useless most of the times when you develop.

Then you use strtotime() http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php to convert the date in string format to a numeric value that can easily be compared.